# jQuery Chosen: Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node':

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-chosen, prototype-chosen

I have a problem impossible to solve by myself. I am debugging this for several days but no success in found where is the problem.

I have a chosen.js + jscrollpane.js. When a chosen is open, the search input field must to be focused to write some search string. The first time that I open the chosen throws an error and I can't search anything inside it. But if I close the chosen and reopen it, all works fine.

I make a fiddle for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/y2h3ohr3/2/

So the error when I open the first time the chosen I can see this error in Chrome's console (in firefox, the error exists but console doesn't throws error):

> Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is no longer a child of this node. Perhaps it was moved in a 'blur' event handler?

The trace that console throws:

> jQuery.extend.buildFragment   @   jquery-1.9.1.js:6541
>
> jQuery.fn.extend.domManip @   jquery-1.9.1.js:6129
>
> jQuery.fn.extend.append   @   jquery-1.9.1.js:5949
>
> initialise    @   jquery.jscrollpane.min.js:115
>
> JScrollPane   @   jquery.jscrollpane.min.js:1388
>
> (anonymous function)  @   jquery.jscrollpane.min.js:1407
>
> jQuery.extend.each    @   jquery-1.9.1.js:648
>
> jQuery.fn.jQuery.each @   jquery-1.9.1.js:270
>
> $.fn.jScrollPane  @   jquery.jscrollpane.min.js:1399
>
> (anonymous function)  @   chosen.jquery.js:774
>
> jQuery.event.dispatch @   jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
>
> elemData.handle   @   jquery-1.9.1.js:2750
>
> jQuery.event.special.focus.trigger    @   jquery-1.9.1.js:3256
>
> jQuery.event.trigger  @   jquery-1.9.1.js:2952
>
> (anonymous function)  @   jquery-1.9.1.js:3677
>
> jQuery.extend.each    @   jquery-1.9.1.js:648
>
> jQuery.fn.jQuery.each @   jquery-1.9.1.js:270
>
> jQuery.fn.extend.trigger  @   jquery-1.9.1.js:3676
>
> jQuery.fn.(anonymous function)    @   jquery-1.9.1.js:7403
>
> $.fn.extend.focus @   jquery-ui.js:230
>
> Chosen.results_show   @   chosen.jquery.js:968
>
> Chosen.container_mousedown    @   chosen.jquery.js:839
>
> (anonymous function)  @   chosen.jquery.js:654
>
> jQuery.event.dispatch @   jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
>
> elemData.handle   @   jquery-1.9.1.js:2750

I make a fiddle, the design it's not the same as in my project, but the error reproduces perfectly (pay attention to chrome console when open first time the chosen).

You can view the fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/y2h3ohr3/2/

Can anyone help me? I'm stucked and I can't make more because I not found the error anywhere. The error is throwing by jquery, not the chosen, so I not made custom `appendChild`.

Comment: I can attach more information, only tell me and I share that you need to view the problem. Thank you

Comment: For me in Firefox it doesn't work anyhow. Can you say for what you use jscrollpane.js? Is it not enough chosen.js? If you explain difference of your approach from demos on [https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) I will try to achieve it at the evening.

Comment: It's a weird specification of the client. It's mandatory to use jscrollpane. Yeah, it's cruft, a shit, and all adjectives you are thinking was thinking by me. But I am unable to remove it. If you see the fiddle, in the code of the chosen is modified to use the jscrollpane, so it's not the same chosen than the original. It's better debugging step-by-step, but I make it and I don't know where is the problem. If you need an specific information, tell me please. Thank you!!

Comment: I just mentioned that it works fine just with chosen.js as in demo. So I try to comprehend difference. Is it has difference or it should work with your custom js?

Comment: Yes, there are tons of differences in the custom chosen. There are modifications by a lot of people, so the code is not the same as the original chosen.js. I think that this problem is caused by jscrollpane, but I can't see the error per se.

Comment: Hi Marcos for me in FF in dorpdown the position of items itself shifted right and its not visible.  but I dont see any JS error.

Comment: @DilipRajkumar in firefox there isn't the error warning, but exists the error, in chrome you can see the error in the console.

Comment: Can you try to reduce your code to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include it here in the question instead of just through a Fiddle link?

Comment: @skrrgwasme this code is minimal, complete and verifiable. Maybe it's not much readable but is impossible to reduce more code. Is the minimal code to reproduce the problem. The entire application are more of 200MB of code inserted in a liferay (yeah, authentic hell). Can you tell me what more you need? There'll be a pleasure to assist you.

Comment: I know the code is long, but it should be included in the question itself instead of only linked. As it stands, your question fits this close reason: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**..." I've opened up a [Meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310334/2615940) that involves this question. Adding the code would resolve my Meta post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the following line:
`pane = $('<div class="jspPane" />').css('padding', originalPadding).append(elem.children());`

Instead of `append` it should be `appendTo` as `div.jsPane` is being added to an existing element.
`pane = $('<div class="jspPane" />').css('padding', originalPadding).appendTo(elem.children());`

See [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/y2h3ohr3/5/)

Comment: Not now, the error disappears, that's fine. But behaviour is still weird

Answer (score 2):

This happens because in line 115 in your fiddle:

```
pane = $('<div class="jspPane" />').css('padding', originalPadding).append(elem.children());
```

you try to append elem.children() to your pane, but when you select something in your select the children your elem change. So jQuery tries to remove and add a child that does not longer exist.
A quick solution would be to clone the elem.children, store them in a var and append the cloned children. Like this:

```
var $children = elem.children().clone();
                    pane = $('<div class="jspPane" />').css('padding', originalPadding).append($children);
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2h3ohr3/6/)

Comment: Unfortunately, this works only first time that I open the chosen. Next times it doesn't works... it's weird because in the fiddle works fine. The same in the @Taleeb solution.